# If $date contains integer '2016'

Tags: php

I'm looking to do some basic PHP to test if a variable contains the current year.

What would be my conditional statement be for this?

My `$date` variable has the formatting like `25 June 2016`.

And could I do a similar conditional statement for the year after?

Comment: http://php.net/date http://php.net/strpos

Comment: $dates = get_field('listing_date');

 $findme   = '2016';
 $pos = strpos($dates, $findme);

 if ($pos === false) {
  $showhide = 'style="display:none"';
 } else {
  $showhide = 'style="display:block"';
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a class [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) you can use.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y', '25 June 2016');
echo $date->format('Y');
```